# Powershell script to copy value of Created By user field to another field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, powershell, 2016

I created a custom list and here I want to copy Created By column value to another field in same list

- Source Field: Created By
- Destination Field: Item Created User (this is Person/Group Field)

I have SP 2013 & Presently no workflows configured. I want to do by Simple PowerShell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this PowerShell script for you

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
$listName = "CustomList1"

#Get the SPWeb object
$web = Get-SPWeb http://spwapp/

#Get the SPList
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

#Get all items in this list
$items = $list.items

#Go through all items
foreach($item in $items)
{
    $created = $item["Created By"]
    $item["DestinationPG"] = $created

    #Update the item
    $item.Update()

}
```

Copy and Paste this script, refer to your **SP2013 site url** and your **List name**, and execute it, it will update all the items at once.

**FROM THIS**
[image]

**TO THIS**
[image]

***If this answers suit you, please upvote and accept it as an answer***

Comment: Hi Aimen, when run this script no changes will happen destinatinfield has empty value, note here that Created By is person group field.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted "Created" column, well, its gonna be the same, i will edit my answer

Comment: @user3520155, here is it, answer edited !

Comment: yes i give Destination Field also Person Group type field but no value copied

Comment: are you sure you are not missing something? it's working perfectly from my side !

Comment: Yes i miss the list name wrong what i added in the list url but list name is different thanks for your help